# How to input a string containing a hash value, and use it with hashlib methods

Tags: python, input, hash, hashlib

I'm working on a project that involves updating a hash chain using given hash values. My problem is that I can't seem to figure out how to use an inputted string as a hash value.

My code

```py
import hashlib

hash1AsText = hashlib.sha256(b"This is my first hash")
# the origional source of the hash value. I wont have this for other hashes

hash1AsHash = ('F7002A5259567B1F993E743D3128B6A97B153EACFC7BB914802DCFB43D23FA2E')
# The string containing the hash value generated from the text above


chain1 = hashlib.sha256() # hash of blank value to start chain 1
#print hash of initial chain
print("\nInitial Chain1:\n",chain1.hexdigest().upper())

# print what is getting added
print("\nUpdated Chain1\nAdding:\t",hash1AsText.hexdigest().upper()) 

chain1.update(hash1AsText.digest()) # update chain using the "hash1AsText" hashlib object
print("New:\t",chain1.hexdigest().upper())


chain2 = hashlib.sha256() # hash of blank value to start chain 2
#print hash of initial chain
print("\nInitial Chain2:\n",chain2.hexdigest().upper())

# print what is getting added
print("\nUpdated chain2\nAdding:\t", bytes(hash1AsHash.encode('utf-8')))

# update chain using string conveted to bytes
chain2.update(bytes(hash1AsHash.encode('utf-8'))) 
print("New:\t",chain2.hexdigest().upper())
```

The output

```
Initial Chain1:
 E3B0C44298FC1C149AFBF4C8996FB92427AE41E4649B934CA495991B7852B855

Updated Chain1
Adding:  F7002A5259567B1F993E743D3128B6A97B153EACFC7BB914802DCFB43D23FA2E
New:     8E252D5D846A88D22F8EA8D55B79065521DA5AD3CBCEA51B826F9ED0B4B7D4CD

Initial Chain2:
 E3B0C44298FC1C149AFBF4C8996FB92427AE41E4649B934CA495991B7852B855

Updated chain2
Adding:  b'F7002A5259567B1F993E743D3128B6A97B153EACFC7BB914802DCFB43D23FA2E'
New:     9E213BC13DA41E1E1AF3216F11D0DECA41EACD1FD3496815D7599F830FD32C1A
```

I'm confused because both "adding" values in the two chains are the same hash, but when they are used to update the initial value, they produce different results.

I assume I am doing something wrong with the formatting while changing the string into a bytes value. Is there some other way to import a string that contains a hash value, convert it to a hashlib object(without rehashing it) and use it with hashlib methods such as .update() ?

Comment: The argument of the second `update`-call is wrong converted from a hexadecimal string to a `bytes` object. Correct would be: [`bytes.fromhex`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=bytes#bytes.fromhex)`(hash1AsHash)`. Then, as expected, the results are the same.

Comment: Thank you so much. I knew it would end up being some simple mistake like that.